# Assigning an element of a multidimensional array to a second array

Tags: array

I have two arrays. The first array is a multidimensional array holding color values.

The 2nd array stores an **active** color from the 1st array. 
How can I assign an element from the multidimensional **colors** array to the 2nd **EXCLUSIVE_COLOR** array?

```
int colors[][3] = {
  { 255, 0, 0 },   
  { 0, 255, 0 },   
  { 0, 0, 255 },   
  { 253, 7, 210 }  
};
int EXCLUSIVE_COLOR[3] = {0};
```

I tried the following but neither seemed to work:

```
    EXCLUSIVE_COLOR = { 
      colors[0][0], 
      colors[0][1], 
      colors[0][2]
    };
    // error: assigning to an array from an initializer list

    EXCLUSIVE_COLOR = colors[0];
    // error: invalid array assignment
```

Comment: what is the type of `EXCLUSIVE_COLOR`. you want a pointer to the array or a copy of the array?

Comment: Either one would work. EXCLUSIVE_COLOR is a 3 element int array.

Comment: `int* EXCLUSIVE_COLOR = colors[0];`. and then you can use `EXCLUSIVE_COLOR[i]`

Comment: Why do you use a two-dimensional array, if you have a one-dimensional array of `Color` elements in reality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the array:

```cpp
EXCLUSIVE_COLOR[0] = colors[0][0];
EXCLUSIVE_COLOR[1] = colors[0][1];
EXCLUSIVE_COLOR[2] = colors[0][2];
```

but this doesn't work in an initialization.

Alternatively, you can declare `EXCLUSIVE_COLOR` as a pointer to an
array of 3 integers:

```cpp
int (*EXCLUSIVE_COLOR)[3]; // pointer to array 3 of int
```

Then you can have this point to a row of the 2D array, either by
assigning the pointer or in the initialization:

```cpp
int (*EXCLUSIVE_COLOR)[3] = &colors[0];  // initialization

// Later in the program:
EXCLUSIVE_COLOR = &colors[1];
```

Note that when using this pointer, you will have to explicitly
dereference it:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    Serial.println((*EXCLUSIVE_COLOR)[i]);
```

**Edit**: As pointed out by Juraj in a comment, you can instead make
`EXCLUSIVE_COLOR` a pointer to int. In this case you will make it point
to the first element in the row you want:

```cpp
int* EXCLUSIVE_COLOR = &colors[0][0];
```

One nice thing of this approach is that you can use the “decay to
pointer” feature of the language to simplify the syntax:

```cpp
int* EXCLUSIVE_COLOR = colors[0];

// Later
Serial.println(EXCLUSIVE_COLOR[i]);
```

Comment: a pointer to pointer? it doesn't look right

Comment: @Juraj: It's not a pointer to pointer, it's a pointer to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays only where appropriate:

```
struct Color {byte r, g, b;};
const Color colors[] = {
  {0,255,0},
  {255,0,0}
};
const Color red = colors[1];
```

This works without `const` as well. But you should consider using `const` wherever possible.