# Setting an array pointer to null on declaration

Tags: array, pointer

How can I set an array pointer to **null**?

I have a pointer to a 3 int array that I am trying to set to **null**.

> int (*EXCLUSIVE_COLOR)[3];

[Per this link](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/76201/assigning-an-empty-array-row-to-reference) I was trying to set it to null upon initialization.
However this does not assign a null value to it. It assigns three 'random' integers to the array elements:

> {128, 447, 451}

How can I make it point to a **null** or **empty** value?

Comment: if you assign null, test it for null, not read it

Comment: What were you expecting to  get when you read a null pointer?  That's undefined behavior.  It could give you anything.  If you want to make the thing pointed to zero then do that.  That's not the same as assigning a null pointer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assigning an element of a multidimensional array to a second array](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/76177/assigning-an-element-of-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-second-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a full example that shows you all thing things you have been asking over the past few days:

```
int colors[][3] = {
    {255, 0, 0},
    {0, 255, 0},
    {0, 0, 255}
};

#define NCOLOR (sizeof(colors) / sizeof(colors[0]))

int *EXCLUSIVE_COLOR = NULL;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.print("You have ");
    Serial.print(NCOLOR);
    Serial.println(" colors defined.");
    reportColor();
    EXCLUSIVE_COLOR = colors[2];
    reportColor();
    EXCLUSIVE_COLOR = NULL;
    reportColor();
}

void loop() {

}

void reportColor() {
    if (!EXCLUSIVE_COLOR) {
        Serial.println("Color is not set");
    } else {
        Serial.print("Color is set to ");
        Serial.print(EXCLUSIVE_COLOR[0]);
        Serial.print(",");
        Serial.print(EXCLUSIVE_COLOR[1]);
        Serial.print(",");
        Serial.println(EXCLUSIVE_COLOR[2]);
    }
}
```

You have an array of colours. You have a pointer that can point at a colour or at nothing. It starts off pointing at nothing. The code recognises that it's pointing at nothing and reports it. It gets assigned to a specific colour in your colours array. The code recognises that it's now a valid value and reports it. The pointer then gets pointed to nothing again. Again the code recognises that and tells you.

The result:

```
You have 3 colors defined.
Color is not set
Color is set to 0,0,255
Color is not set
```